# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" occurred while reading image of size 330MB

Tags: java, image-processing, out-of-memory, java-io

I'm using following code to read image file of size 330MB

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read("test.png");
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Google how to use -Xmx

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the value of heap using the -Xmx. From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard)

> Specifies the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool.
>   This value must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2 MB. Append the
>   letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes.
>   The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration.

Comment: That is done ......but Still facing same Exception